# Creating desktop folder that ONLY displays shortcuts

Tags: windows

Is there a way to create a folder on the desktop that only displays the files or shortcuts inside of it?

For instance normally if you create a new folder and you open it, it opens up in Windows Explorer... it shows all the quick access folders and drive letters on the left and up top shows all the different options, etc...

I'm trying to create a folder that when you open it it has nothing in it whatsoever besides the files or shortcuts you put in it...

What Explorer looks like now:
[image]

What I want to see:
[image]

Comment: You'd have to replace File Explorer or make a shortcut to another exe that can visually do it, then replace that shortcut or EXE icon as a folder icon

Comment: Don't use explorer at all. There are launchers that basically do exactly this, except rather than using shortcuts in a folder, you drag shortcuts to the launcher to add them. There are plenty.